# How do I get the country of the delivery address from a shipping rate request?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-address

From all I know `$request->getCountryId()` should return the country of the delivery address as a two-digit ISO code.

But for me it always returns DE (the location of the store) instead of the country of the delivery address.

Comment: try `$request->getDestCountryId();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want **shipping address** `Country Id`. try below code

```
$request->getDestCountryId();
```